# RestRequest add paramters not working Delphi Rad Studio

Tags: web-services, delphi, restful-url

When put value of parameters 'New York' my restful not return result, but when put 'Paris' working fine.

```
with RestRequest.Params.AddItem do
    begin
      name := 'city';
      Value := 'New York';
      Kind := TRestRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST;
    end;
```

I think that problem is space! How fix that?

After call restful online from oracle apex and send value 'New York' working fine. In url stay 'New%20York' I'm try put in delphi 'New%20York' but not result.